# Number of walks of length $n$ from $x$ to $y$ for $x\neq y$ in $K_{100}$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $K_{100}$ denote the complete graph with $100$ vertices.
How many walks of length $n$ are there from $x$ to $y$ for $x\neq y$?

The solution was this:
Let $v$ be the second last vertex in a walk from $x$ to $y$.
Since $K_{100}$ has no loops, then $v\neq y$.
Once the second last vertex is known, we only have one choice to go to $y$.
Let $a_n$ be the required number of walks.
Suppose that $v\neq x,y$.
 1. Choose $v$ in $98$ ways.
 2. Choose a walk from $x$ to $v$ in $a_{n-1}$ ways.
Now suppose that $v=x$. Then let $u$ be the third last vertex in the walk.
Then now we count walks $x\rightarrow \ldots\rightarrow u \rightarrow x\rightarrow y$
 3. Choose $u$ in $99$ ways
 4. Choose a walk of length $n-2$ from $x$ to $u$ in $a_{n-2}$ ways.
So $a_n = 98a_{n-1} + 99a_{n-2}$.

I don't understand step $3$. How can $u$ have $99$ choices? Since it's a simple graph, $u\neq x$ so shouldn't we only have $98$ choices for $u$?

Comment: If you already studied Markov chains, you can easily realize that the wanted problem id equivalent to finding the $n$-th power of a $100\times 100$ matrix $M=U-I$, where the entries of $U$ are $1$s only. We have $$\text{Spec}(M)=-1+\text{Spec}(U) = \{99,-1,\ldots,-1\}$$ hence it is pretty clear what the characteristic polynomial of $M$ (which is also the characteristic polynomial of the wanted recurrence by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem) really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But we *can* have $u = y$. That means we still have $99$ vertices to choose from, as $x$ is the only disallowed one.